# indexOf() vs regex for identifying special characters like $ and {

Tags: java, regex, indexof

I would like to check if a special character like `{` or `$`is present in a string or not. I used regexp but during code review I was asked to use indexOf() instead regex( as its costlier). I would like to understand how indexOf() is used to identify special characters. (I familiar that this can be done to index substring)

```
String photoRoot = "http://someurl/${TOKEN1}/${TOKEN2}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.*?)\\}");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(photoRoot);
                    if (m.find()) {
                        // logic to be performed
                    }
```

Comment: are you asking how to use indexOf to find out whether a character is present in a string or you're asking about runtime complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more then one indexOf(...) methods but all of them treat all characters the same, there is no need to escape any characters while using these methods.

Here is how you can get the two tokens by using some of the `indexOf(...)` methods:

```
String photoRoot = "http://someurl/${TOKEN1}/${TOKEN2}";
String startDelimiter = "${";
char endDelimiter = '}';
int start = -1, end = -1;
while (true) {
    start = photoRoot.indexOf(startDelimiter, end);
    end = photoRoot.indexOf(endDelimiter, start + startDelimiter.length());
    if (start != -1 && end != -1) {
        System.out.println(photoRoot.substring(start + startDelimiter.length(), end));
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking to find a couple of different special characters you'd just use indexOf("$") or indexOf("}"). You will need to specify each special character you want to find separately.

There is no way though to have it find the index of every special character in one statement: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check for 2 characters as in your question, the answer will be

```
var found = photoRoot.indexOf("$") >=0 ||| photoRoot.indexOf("?") >=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always difficult to guess while there is contradicting information. The code does not look for *special characters*, it searches for a *pattern* - and indexOf will not help you there.

Titus' answer is good for avoiding pattern matching if you need to find the pattern `${...}` (as opposed to "identifying special characters")

If (as the reviewer appears to think) you just need to look for any of a set of special characters you can apply indexOf( on_special_char ) repeatedly, but you can also do

```
for( int i = 0; i < photoRoot.length(); ++i ){
    if( "${}".indexOf( photoRoot.charAt(i) ) >= 0 ){
        // one of the special characters is at pos i
    }
}
```

Not sure where the performance "break even" between multiple indexOf calls on the target string and the (above) iteration on the target with indexOf on the (short) string containing the specials is. But it may be easier to maintain and permits dynamic adaption to the set of specials.

Of course, the simple

```
photoRoot.matches( ".*" + Pattern.quote( specials ) + ".*" );
```

is also dynamically adaptable.